# When navigating on a site, how can i make animations complete fully before browser jumps pages

Tags: navigation, pageload, animate.css

i want to use animate.css in my webpage, on the navigation menu. E.g the menu flies out of the screen navigating. The main problem is: How i can delay the page load that i'm clicking until the animation is fully complete. Right now the animation is cut off because next page loads.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated shake');
        window.setTimeout( function(){
        $('#list').removeClass('animated shake');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is promise() in jQuery > 1.6 . You can queue request of going further waiting for promise().

```
$("button").on( "click", function() {
  $("p").append( "Started...");

  $("div").each(function( i ) {
    $( this ).fadeIn().fadeOut( 1000 * (i+1) );
  });

  $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
    $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: I'm sorry but i am too inexperienced to understand how i can use it with my code/problem. The thing is, i have an unordered list with id "list" which consists of links and i want it to animate when i click on a link, but the animation is cut off due to the new page being loaded. I really don't understand how i must use promise() with it.